# How to change regex coloring in PyCharm

Tags: python, regex, pycharm

I know PyCharm lets you customize font coloring from the program level, in settings but I can't quite pull it off when it comes to regex.

There are lots of options for regex there but option I can't find is one that deals with backgroup color. There is this light yellow/green color which I would like to get rid of. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->General

On the right side, choose "code"->"Injected language fragment"

You can change or remove the background color.
[image]

The side effect is that it will also affect other syntax such as SQL in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Prefix your regexp with r :

```
pattern = r'\d-\d-\d'
```

If it is not enough maybe https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2917?pr=phpStorm

Comment: The prefix will not cut it. And the plugin is irrelevant I guess.